# Excel 2007 - Transpose data format into columns every 6 rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I've exported data in XML format and at the moment it's pretty unusable after I converted to Excel.

The dataset is pretty big (and I expect I'll be running the same exercise more times, with potentially larger sets).

The data is currently in two columns (one column is the titles repeating every 6 rows and the other is the data related to each title).

I need to transform this into 6 columns with the results in the rows underneath (PICTURE, from Blue to Red)

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

Place the header row manually.  Then, in the cell below the first header enter:

```
=OFFSET($C$2,COLUMNS($A:A)-1+(ROWS($1:1)-1)*6,0)
```

copy this cell both across and down:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, I can't seem to get it to work (even after using the equivalent equations in Spanish Excel). I've even tried to use the equation wizard for the OFFSET function (or DESREF) and I can't seem to get anything.